# Entity Framework Core - How can I dynamically log related entity property changes during SaveChanges by using Generic Method?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, entity-framework-core, savechanges

I am recently learning EF Core around Audit ChangeLog part, where I found out most of resource that are only tracking log as direct property of an Entity by using reflection, suppose I have two related entities:

```
public Class Order
{
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public int OrderName {get; set;}
    public virtual Collection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; } = new Collection<OrderDetail>();
}
public Class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailId {get; set;}
    public int OrderDetailName {get; set;}
    public int OrderDetailQuantity {get; set;}
    public int? OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual Order OrderFk { get; set; }
}
```

Then my TrackChange would be like:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<ChangeLog> TrackChange()
{
    foreach (var entry in DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {  
        var entityType = entry.Entity.GetType();

        foreach (var property in entityType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
        {
            var originalValue = entry.Property(property.Name).OriginalValue;
            var currentValue = entry.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue;

            //Log if originalValue != currentValue 
        }
    }
}
```

So if I have an Order contains 3 OrderDetails then I modify **Order Name** and **one of the OrderDetail by updating the OrderDetailQuantity** and save as Order, the TrackChange would catch my OrderName change since this is a property of Order, but **when the "property in entityType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties" becomes "OrderDetails"**, it does not smart enough to detect this is a collection or related entity of "Order", then I get an exception when trying to get originalValue saying:

```
'The property 'OrderDetails' on entity type 'Order' is being accessed using the 'Property' method, but is defined in the model as a navigation property. Use either the 'Reference' or 'Collection' method to access navigation properties.'
```

I know I can probably use entry.Collection(property.Name) to go into the "OrderDetail" collection but the question would be: **How would I know that the current property is a value type like Int/String/Datetime while it could also be  related entity or a collection of the current entry?**

Other thoughts on TrackChange and below is my pseudo code idea:

```
function TrackChange(Entity)
   //Track Base Entity Change
   ...
   //Track Child Entity Change if there is any
   if (Entity.HasChildNode) 
   {
      foreach(ChildEntity of Entity.ChildEntities)
           TrackChange(ChildEntity);
   }
   ...
}
```

Because my TrackChange is Generic so I am hoping there is a way for implementing above idea using C# reflection.

Comment: DbContext.ChangeTracker should have all entities that changed.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but my function would generate an exception when using the reflection to get property in two places: 1) when property becomes "OrderDetails" when entry is "Order" 2)when property becomes "Order" when entry is "OrderDetail", it would be work well if current entry does not have any related entity.